# why is hibernate validations not working?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have added hibernate validation anotations to my DTO and in the controller i have added @Valid anotation, but when i hit the rest end point using postman instead of throwing an error due to invalid input its storing the data in the database.

Here is my Dto class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CategoryDto {

    @Email
    private String name;
    @NotNull(message = "Cannot be null")
    private String imageUrl;
    private String message;

    public CategoryDto(Category category, String message) {
        this.name = category.getName();
        this.imageUrl = category.getImageUrl();
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

Here is my controller class:

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/add")
    public ResponseEntity<Category> addCategory(@Valid @RequestBody CategoryDto categoryDto) throws CategoryAlreadyExistsException {
        Category categoryDetail = categoryService.addCategory(new Category(categoryDto));
        return new ResponseEntity<>(categoryDetail, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

Here is the service class:

```
    @Override
    public Category addCategory(Category category) throws CategoryAlreadyExistsException {
        if (categoryRepository.findById(category.getName()).isPresent()) {
            throw new CategoryAlreadyExistsException(ExceptionMessage.CATEGORYALREADYEXISTS);
        }
        return categoryRepository.save(category);
    }
```

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.0-SNAPSHOT'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'org.sonarqube' version '3.0'
    id 'jacoco'
}

group = 'com.project'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '15'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/snapshot' }
}

dependencies {
    implementation group: 'org.springdoc', name: 'springdoc-openapi-ui', version: '1.5.5'
    implementation group: 'org.hibernate.validator', name: 'hibernate-validator', version: '7.0.1.Final'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
//  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server'
//  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

sonarqube {
    properties {
        property 'sonar.host.url', 'http://localhost:9000'
        property 'sonar.login' , 'admin'
        property 'sonar.password', 'J*j*ts*'
    }
}

//jar {
//  manifest {
//      attributes "Main-Class": "GeckoApplication"
//  }
//}

jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.enabled true
    }
}
```

I don't know why spring boot is behaving like this. It should actually throw a MethodArgumentNotValidException but instead it is not even validating the input, it directly stores the data in the database.
Here is my Json request:

```
{
    "name": "asdkald",
    "imageurl": ""
}
```

```
{
    "name": "asdkald"
}
```

I tried different ways but its not working. Here is the url which i tried to hit "localhost:8090/gecko/category/add". I used postman to hit the rest end point.

Comment: provide your json request

Comment: try to add @Validated annotation to your controller class

Comment: Why is spring-boot-starter-validation commented?

Comment: Adding @Validated to the controller did not work

Answer (score 0):

It was due to the version of hibernate validator. I changed the version from 7.0.1.Final to 6.1.5.Final and everything started to work